# More efficient way of grabbing html from websites? Python Urllib2

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

The function I'm using to grab html from pages seems to be taking a lot of time and in effect slowing down my program considerably. It's very basic but the code is:

```
def get_html(url):
    print 'get_html initialising...'
    open_url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = open_url.read()
    open_url.close()
    return data
```

And the `timeme` results are:

```
http://bloomberg.com/
get_html initialising...
(760, 'ms')
GetLinks initialising...
(121, 'ms')
SaveFiles initialising...
No meta-type match!
(116, 'ms')
```

Any advice or pointers you could offer would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No, not really. You can use `multiprocessing` or `threading` to spread waiting for multiple urls across multiple CPUs or threads, but that's about it.

Comment: Network latency and remote server response times are pretty much out of your control otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, will look into threading to speed this up a bit.